# Using winapi to simulate mouse clicks and scroll in a window (android emulator)

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to simulate clicks (finger taps in my case) and scrolls in a window, android emulator specifically. The code is simple:

```
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(200, 400));
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(200, 500));
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(200, 500));
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
```

And it works fine, except if the real mouse cursor is over that window it interferes with simulated mouse movement. 
So if for example the code is supposed to scroll up and the mouse cursor is moving the opposite way of simulated movement, the application is trying to scroll both ways at the same time.

Is there any way to block the real mouse input for a specific window while this code is executing? 
Or maybe any other way to stop the real mouse from interfering?

Comment: Perhaps you can confine the cursor? https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/menurc/using-cursors#confining-a-cursor

Comment: I guess I could confine it outside the window as the last resort, but I am looking for  something less intrusive for user experience